# If a hand was suddenly chopped off while holding something, would the severed hand still hold a grip?

Tags: injury

This question was inspired by *Star Wars Episode V: The Empire Strikes Back*. In it, Luke Skywalker is battling Darth Vader in a lightsaber duel. Vader manages to win out and chops off Luke's hand, which is holding the lightsaber.

[image: Luke Skywalker loses his hand in a lightsaber battle with Darth VAder]

My question is: would his severed hand still hold a grip on the lightsaber? Or would it fall slack and lose grip, likely separating as it falls into the pit?

While this question is from a sci-fi series with a fantasy means of dismemberment, it might apply to other real-world situations (for instance, an industrial worker holding a tool while a piece of machinery accidentally severs his hand).

Comment: It seems unlikely, since most of the muscles that provide the gripping force are in the forearm.  Try gripping something forcefully* and notice which muscles tense up.  (*Of course anyone who's done much fencing knows that you don't grip with too much force.)

Comment: @jamesqf I'm not real fond of this type of question, but it seems like you could make a simple answer out of that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I have no personal or medical experience of cutting off hands, or any other body parts, so this is purely theoretical.)

It seems unlikely, since most of the muscles that provide the gripping force are in the forearm and are transmitted via tendons in the wrists. Try gripping something forcefully* and notice which muscles tense up, and how the tendons on the inside of the wrist transmit the force.  Cutting the tendons would eliminate the force.

Of course anyone who's done much fencing knows that you don't grip with too much force, because that interferes with the fine control provided by the fingers.